# Java Hyperlink to file in text editor

Tags: java, eclipse, hyperlink, editor, javadoc

I have a question related to hyperlinks in java. 
How can I set hyperlink in java file to point to another java file loaded on the text editor in Eclipse, when I have the filename and code line:

ex. `Test.java:102`

How to show the given code line of that file on the text editor?

Thank you!

Comment: Please try and ammend your question and add _what_ you are trying to achieve as well as the _why_ you want to achieve it. Normally, there should be no reason to link to a specific line in another Java file.

Comment: I am working with Swing Components and I have the code lines where specific component is created ex. a JButton on Test.java:102. So I want to make hyperlink to that file Test.java on that code line.

Comment: I presume you want to do this to leave some kind of hint to other developers. You're better off leaving a comment within the code with the name of the button (which you should be able to set as a property). If it would be possible to make a hyperlink to a line, then the next time you add a component, you would be pointing to the wrong spot. If your code does allow edits, you can also leave a comment that creates a TAG in Eclipse at the spot you want to point to.

Answer (score 0):

The Java *language* does not know hyperlinks.

JavaDoc does know hyperlinks, which you can easily access in the Eclipse editor by typing either the # sign and choose a local member or by typing the name of an external class and hitting <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>, then choose the right link.

Fortunately, you cannot directly create links to lines. Lines change in time, the contract of the class (the description of the methods/fields) is what should remain relatively static. When configured correctly, Eclipse will even change your links if you refactor your code (e.g. rename your method or class).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create hyperlinks to lines -afaik, but you can create links to fields or functions in javadoc:

```
/**
 * {@link package.ClassName#fieldOrFunction}
 */
```

doing it like that allows you to ctrl-click on the "fieldOrFunction" and jumps right there (at least in eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

2 years later, I know...

If you are looking for hyperlinks from any file surround it with parenthesis like so
(AnotherClass.java:52)

ctrl click will take you there if it knows of that class.